# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory' not working

Tags: python, django, email-verification

I wanna have a website which verifies it's users by sending them verification email. searching for a good tutorial, I came to [this](https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangousercreation.html#prettyPhoto)
 which helped me a lot; but still I have problems.

I don't know why no email is sent to the sample email which I registered with, nor is written in PyCharm terminal (as it's said in the tutorial).

would you please help me, at which part am I making mistake?

my code :

#settings.py

```
SITE_ID = 1

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                "django.template.context_processors.media",

            ],
        },
    },
]
# Custom allauth settings
# Use email as the primary identifier
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# Make email verification mandatory to avoid junk email accounts
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
# Eliminate need to provide username, as it's a very old practice
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin and to ensure compatibility with other packages
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # 'allauth' specific authentication methods
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

#urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    url(r'^$', views.main_page),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', views.home),
    url(r'^wallets/', views.wallets),
    url(r'^trans-history/', views.trans_history),
    url(r'^reports/', views.reports, name='reports'),
    url(r'^general/', views.home, name='general'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

#views.py

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        registration_form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and registration_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = registration_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            profile.user = user

            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']
            profile.save()
            registered = True

            new_user = authenticate(username=user_form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    password=user_form.cleaned_data['password'], )
            login(request, new_user)

        else:
            print user_form.errors, registration_form.errors

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        registration_form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': registration_form, 'registered': registered})
```

and my forms.py :

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')

    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', '')
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password", '')
        if password != confirm_password:
            print("error")
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match!")
        return confirm_password



class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user', 'email']
```

Comment: are you using django-allauth?

Comment: `console.EmailBackend` will not send emails, it just show in terminal only. it is for dev purpose.

Comment: yea i know, but the question is what to do now ? BTW, it doesn't show in the terminal neither @itzmeontv

Comment: As @itzmeontv has pointed out console.EmailBackend will not send mail. not sure if this will work even after that. Why are you using your own register view and form if you are using allauth?